# Remove objects with a duplicate property from List

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a List of objects in C#.  All of the objects contain a property ID.
There are several objects that have the same ID property.

How can I trim the List (or make a new List) where there is only one object per ID property?

[Any additional duplicates are dropped out of the List]

Answer (score 227, accepted):

If you want to avoid using a third-party library, you could do something like:

```
var bar = fooArray.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

That will group the array by the Id property, then select the first entry in the grouping.

Comment: This worked perfectly here is my implementation:

List<InputRow> uniqueRows = inputRows.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList<InputRow>();

Comment: Glad to help! One note: The `<InputRow>` on your `ToList()` is redundant. You should be able to just do `.ToList()`

Comment: You are right it works with just ToList() instead of ToList<InputRow>()

Comment: a good alternatif than trying to figure out why using distinct and iquatable not working.

Answer (score 37):

MoreLINQ `DistinctBy()` will do the job, it allows using object proeprty for the distinctness. Unfortunatly built in LINQ `Distinct()` not flexible enoght.

```
var uniqueItems = allItems.DistinctBy(i => i.Id);
```

**DistinctBy()**

> Returns all distinct elements of the given source, where
>   "distinctness" is determined via a projection and the default eqaulity
>   comparer for the projected type.

- [Download MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)
- [DistinctBy() sources](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs)

PS: Credits to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for sharing this library with community

Comment: I think this is a great solution but am trying to avoid using a 3rd party library for this.  Thank You.

Comment: Fortunately you can see how it is implemented

Answer (score 13):

Starting from .NET 6, a new [`DistinctBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby) LINQ operator is available:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource,TKey> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector);
```

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence according to a specified key selector function.

Usage example:

```
List<Item> distinctList = listWithDuplicates
    .DistinctBy(i => i.Id)
    .ToList();
```

There is also an overload that has an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` parameter.

---

**Update in-place:** In case creating a new `List<T>` is not desirable, here is a `RemoveDuplicates` extension method for the `List<T>` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes all the elements that are duplicates of previous elements,
/// according to a specified key selector function.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// The number of elements removed.
/// </returns>
public static int RemoveDuplicates<TSource, TKey>(
    this List<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(keySelector);
    HashSet<TKey> hashSet = new(keyComparer);
    return source.RemoveAll(item => !hashSet.Add(keySelector(item)));
}
```

This method is efficient (O(n)) but also a bit dangerous, because it is based on the potentially corruptive [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) method¹. In case the `keySelector` lambda succeeds for some elements and then fails for another element, the partially modified `List<T>`
will neither be restored to its initial state, nor it will be in a state recognizable as the result of successful individual `Remove`s.
Instead it will transition to a corrupted state that includes duplicate occurrences of existing elements. So in case the `keySelector` lambda is not
fail-proof, the `RemoveDuplicates` method should be invoked in a `try` block that has a `catch` block where the potentially corrupted list is discarded.

Alternatively you could substitute the dangerous built-in `RemoveAll` with a safe [custom implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027446/how-to-implement-a-specialized-overload-of-the-list-removeall-method-with-an-in/75039907#75039907), that offers predictable behavior.

¹ <sub>For all .NET versions and platforms, including the latest .NET 7. I have submitted [a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66255) on GitHub to document the corruptive behavior of the `List<T>.RemoveAll` method, and the feedback that I received was that neither the behavior should be documented, nor the implementation should be fixed.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

```
var list = GetListFromSomeWhere();
var list2 = GetListFromSomeWhere();
list.AddRange(list2);

....
...
var distinctedList = list.DistinctBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

`More LINQ` at [GitHub](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

Or if you don't want to use external dlls for some reason, You can use this `Distinct` overload:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
```

Usage:

```
public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.ID == y.ID
    }
}



list.Distinct(new FooComparer());
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for any additional ways to do this.  But I've used this code to remove duplicates from a list of User objects based on matching ID numbers.

```cs
private ArrayList RemoveSearchDuplicates(ArrayList SearchResults)
{
    ArrayList TempList = new ArrayList();

    foreach (User u1 in SearchResults)
    {
        bool duplicatefound = false;
        foreach (User u2 in TempList)
            if (u1.ID == u2.ID)
                duplicatefound = true;

        if (!duplicatefound)
            TempList.Add(u1);
    }
    return TempList;
}
```

Call:  `SearchResults = RemoveSearchDuplicates(SearchResults);`

Comment: This is pointlessly O(n ^2) when regular GroupBy is just O(n)...